# Can we use Multiple Count(Column) with where cluase for each count in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select Category,COUNT(HId) as Ticket 
from tblHelpdeskCalls 
Group by Category

Select Category,COUNT(HId) as Processing 
from tblHelpdeskCalls 
where CallStatus='Processing' 
Group by Category

Select Category, COUNT(HId) as Accepted 
from tblHelpdeskCalls 
where CallStatus='Accepted' 
Group by Category
```

etc

Make its appear in a single statement

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but have you considered ROLLUP grouping? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#group-by-rollup

Answer (score 4):

Use *conditional* aggregation:

```
select category,
       count(*) Ticket,
       sum(case when CallStatus = 'Processing' then 1 else 0 end) Processing,
       sum(case when CallStatus = 'Accepted' then 1 else 0 end) Accepted
from tblHelpdeskCalls t
group by category;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could still use `COUNT`:

```
SELECT category,
       Ticket     = COUNT(*),
       Processing = COUNT(CASE WHEN CallStatus = 'Processing' THEN HId END),
       Accepted   = COUNT(CASE WHEN CallStatus = 'Accepted'   THEN HId END)
FROM tblHelpdeskCalls
GROUP BY category;
```

Default for `CASE` when not `WHEN` is matched is `NULL` and aggregation functions skip `NULL` values.

Comment: This raises `Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation` warning. What is `Ticket = COUNT(*) Ticket` about?

Comment: @wqw This is only warning that inform you about skipping NULLs. `Ticket = COUNT(*)` is T-SQL dialect extension same as `COUNT(*) AS Ticket`

Comment: The original `Ticket = COUNT(*) Ticket` gave me syntax error -- I can see you have fixed it after my comment. The warning is still there to annoy everyone.

Comment: @wqw Yes, I corrected my answer. Anyway if you don't like this message you could turn it off `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;` but I don't recommend it.

Comment: Ok, this is useful info. I wouldn't recommend writing T-SQL (or any other) code w/ warnings either.

Comment: @wqw You still miss the point of this warning. Simple demo without conditional aggregation for you: [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3e9c04ac3175a0c45538e39efe1808a1) and [Demo PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a93707187881e976ce7bd3c17d31e7aa) As you see you get warning(and rather *info* that NULL values are not considered when calculating agg function)

Comment: In your last sample change COUNT aggregate to AVG and observe you get *wrong* results. This warning is not harmless, please stop spreading code that produces warnings as the results from such queries are mostly wrong for the purposes most users would need. Depending on the side effect of COUNT(expr) not counting NULLs is not "inventive", more so when SUM can be used rather straightforward and has been the cannonical solution on conditional counting for ages.

Comment: @wpw `"In your last sample change COUNT aggregate to AVG and observe you get wrong results." and "Depending on the side effect of COUNT(expr) not counting NULLs is not "inventive""`  Is it a joke? My solution has nothing to do with inventivness. It is how agg function work in general. Here example with `AVG` from [PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=48a8b223b6959b761f4719f7ffc0e2ef) you will get **1** and not **0.5** and no warning at all. So if you want to prove that `SUM` is better than `COUNT` it is a wrong place. Anyway feel free to use solution that suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

First, we group by category and count:

```
select category,
       count(*) Ticket
  from tblHelpdeskCalls
 group by category;
```

Secondly, Second, it differentiates the cases of CallStatus (Processing/Accepted). We can do this using "case when" or "decode":

Using "case when" (Proposed by Yogesh Sharma and lad2025):

```
select category,
       count(*) Ticket,
       sum(case when CallStatus = 'Processing' then 1 else 0 end) Processing,
       sum(case when CallStatus = 'Accepted' then 1 else 0 end) Accepted
  from tblHelpdeskCalls
 group by category;
```

Using "decode":

```
select category,
       count(*) Ticket,
       sum( decode(CallStatus, 'Processing', 1, 0) ) Processing,
       sum( decode(CallStatus, 'Accepted'  , 1, 0) ) Accepted
  from tblHelpdeskCalls
 group by category;
```