# SQL query to count different records and print in 1 row

Tags: sql, firebird

I have the following table and I am looking for a SQL query which counts the rewards for each name and also print the last date a specific reward type was earned.

This is my table:

```
   NAME   |   REWARD    |    DATE
----------+-------------+------------
  Chris   |    small    |  18.05.2014
  Chris   |    small    |  27.08.2015
  Chris   |    big      |  01.07.2014
  Tom     |    big      |  10.10.2016
  Tom     |    big      |  30.11.2017
```

The result should look like this:

```
   NAME   | BIG_REWARDS | SMALL_REWARDS | LAST_BIG_REWARD | LAST_SMALL_REWARD
----------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------------
  Chris   |      1      |       2       |    01.07.2014   |    27.08.2015
  Tom     |      2      |       0       |    30.11.2017   |
```

I am using Firebird

Comment: What version of Firebird?

Comment: 2.5 but the question was answered already

Comment: I ask because FB 3 offers [a different class of solutions](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs.html) to this kind of problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT name,  
      SUM(CASE WHEN reward = 'big'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BIG_REWARDS,
      SUM(CASE WHEN reward = 'small' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SMALL_REWARDS,        
      MAX(CASE WHEN reward = 'big'   THEN "DATE" END) AS LAST_BIG_REWARD,
      MAX(CASE WHEN reward = 'small' THEN "DATE" END) AS LAST_SMALL_REWARD
FROM tab
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: You can also use `count(case when reward = 'big' then 1 end)` and `count(case when reward = 'small' then 1 end)` instead of `sum`. That might more clearly convey that things are counted.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, thanks for suggestion and edit. I agree about `COUNT` but some users don't like this approach like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50186275/5070879)